# Method .map don't work in application React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks, fetch

the .map method of the object doesn't work, I can't interact with the object of the API I imported.        On the console of browser i read the object.

This is a component razze("races")

```
const BASE_URL = "https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races";



const ListaRazze = () => {
  const [razze, setRazze] = useState<RazzeArray>();

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(BASE_URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((results) => {
        console.log('result', results);
        setRazze(results);

        const prova = Object.values(results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    
     <>
      {razze && razze.razze ? (
        razze.razze.map(({ indice, name, url }) => (
          <div key={indice}>{name} {url}</div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default ListaRazze;
```

This is interface in a package models

```
export interface RazzeArray {
    count: number
    razze: Razza[]
  }
  
  export interface Razza {
    indice: number
    name: string
    url: string
  }
```

Being able to enter the object

Comment: setRazze(results);  must not be setting an array

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  What is the observed runtime value of `razze` when the problem occurs and what specifically is the problem?

Comment: @terpinmd U have alright, but i think is more correctly this.     const [razze, setRazze] = useState<RazzeArray>(Object);

Comment: @David The code dont enter here       {razze && razze.razze ? (
        razze.razze.map(({ indice, name, url }) => (
          <div key={indice}>{name} {url}</div>
        ))
      ) and skip here (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </>

Comment: What does the `results` object from the `fetch` call look like?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier this is the look https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani: By "the code does not enter here" do you mean that the condition `razze && razze.razze` is `false`?  Well, when you actually look at your data, why do you expect that condition to be true?

Comment: @David I have simplified the condition:     razze.razze.map(({ indice, name, url }) => (
  <div key={indice}>{name} {url}</div>
))  the error code is : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani: Then `razze.razze` is `undefined`, which is why the condition was evaluating to `false`.  `undefined` is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Comment: @David But if i see the log in console.... i dont understand because razze.razze is undefined

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani: And what *specifically* are you seeing in the console?

Comment: @David i see in console before "result {count: 9, results: Array(9)}" and after Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at ListaRazze (razze.tsx:24:1). The first message in console it serves to show me the imported api

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani: So you are observing that the object has two properties: `count` and `results`.  What value are you expecting a property called `razze` to have and why?  For what specific reason are you expecting to use a property which you have observed does not exist?

Comment: @David Sure, the value i'm expecting is a cicle ".map()" for the view in browser the list of the races

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani: Well, unless there's some indication of *why* you're expecting a property on that object which you have observed *does not exist*, there's little that can be done to help you.  The property doesn't exist.  It's not there.  Your own debugging has confirmed this.  It seems likely to me that you *meant* to use a property that *is* there, such as the `results` property.  But if you truly are continuing to expect a property which doesn't exist to somehow exist, then I'm afraid your expectations are simply wrong.  Something has to exist in order for it to exist.

Comment: @LorenzoGaetani you need to **edit your question** and include all this relevant information in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you're receiving is different from the data you're expecting in your interfaces. Observe the properties of your [api result](https://www.dnd5eapi.co/api/races) and match the property names.

I'd also recommend that you keep your code in English for consistency and clarity.

```
export interface IRaceList {
  count: number
  results: IRace[]
}
  
export interface IRace {
  index: number
  name: string
  url: string
}
```

Set an initial value for your state. This too will make your code more predictable and consistant. If you don't want an initial state, then make sure the types reflect that.

```
const RaceList = () => {
  const [raceList, setRaceList] = useState<IRaceList>({
    count: 0,
    results: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(BASE_URL)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((results: IRaceList) => {
        setRaceList(results);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
     <>
      {raceList.count ? (
        raceList.results.map(({ index, name, url }) => (
          <div key={index}>{name} {url}</div>
        ))
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```